# SelectPdf - NET Core 3.1 - Failed to convert HTML to PDF on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, pdf, .net-core, selectpdf

I have a .NET Core 3.1 web app running on Azure App Service that is using SelectPdf to convert some HTML document to PDF. It is working perfectly on my localhost but once I publish on to Azure, I got the following error no matter how small/simple my HTML document is:

```
System.Exception: Could not get conversion result header. Data transfer error. Data transmission error 109
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToImage.ᜀ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, ជ& A_3, String& A_4)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜁ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(String htmlString)
```

My current app service is on the basic Dev/Test plan (does this even matter)?

Comment: There are some limitations: https://selectpdf.com/docs/SelectPdf-Microsoft-Azure.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclosure: I work for SelectPdf.*

I am afraid that it matters what plan you are using on Azure. Azure has a lot of limitations and SelectPdf uses an alternate rendering engine on Azure. To test it on your computer, you need to set:

```
GlobalProperties.EnableRestrictedRenderingEngine = true;
```

SelectPdf requires an Azure App Service Plan starting with Basic (does not work with Free/Shared plans).

More details about deployments to Azure can be found here:
https://selectpdf.com/docs/SelectPdf-Microsoft-Azure.htm

Comment: Thx for the comment! The document mentioned that with the Basic plan it would work but it "support only for single page PdfHtmlElement objects". Does this mean I can't convert HTML document to pdf if it's longer than 1 page?

Comment: You can convert multi-page documents if you use the main HtmlToPdf object. The limitation applies only for PdfHtmlElement objects.